# design pattern for unlimited number of conditions

Tags: oop, design-patterns

I wonder what design pattern I can use to replace unlimited number of conditions.

a more straightforward question :
How to make tool like LinPEASE.sh in oop way that lets many users add their own logic . (I just bring this tool as an example because it has many many if conditions, and the amount of conditions in it grow over time)
https://github.com/carlospolop/privilege-escalation-awesome-scripts-suite/tree/master/linPEAS

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve ?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at LinPEASE.sh, it's basically just a bunch of if statements in sequence. If you wanted to achieve the same functionality, but make it dynamic so that additional checks and operations could be added using a design pattern, Chain of Responsibility seems well suited.

Answer (score -1):

As per me this case is best suited for a Rule engine like drools.
https://www.drools.org/

Comment: Please don't promote products and services, as an answer to a question. And the question itself is off-topic.